# How to I make R finding gdal-config?

Tags: r, gdal, r-sf

I would like to install the "sf" package in R. However, when trying to install the library using `install.packages("sf")`, I receive following error message:

```
 installing *source* package ‘sf’ ...
** package ‘sf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
configure: CC: clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13
configure: CXX: clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++14
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/Users/username/Documents/GIS/projectname/renv/staging/1/sf’
```

I am working on a MACOS (12.6.6) without administrator privileges. Therefore, I installed Anaconda/Conda, created a new environment and installed "gdal".
GDAL is therefore installed and a "gdal-config" file is available under `/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/project/bin/gdal-config`. Nevertheless, I receive the above error message when I try `install.packages("sf")`.

What do I need to do so that R will find the GDAL installation, respectively the "gdal-config" file?

Comment: If and when `gdal-config` is in the $PATH, R will find it. If it is not in the $PATH you have to add it. On some OSs installing it (usually as part of something call `libgdal-dev` or `libgdal-devel` or alike) is enough, on others (Windows!!) you have to do more.

Comment: More broadly speaking, any use and installation setup that gives you binaries (with dependencies) will give you `sf`.  A few days ago I illustrated a use case in the cloud via 'codespaces' based on Ubuntu and r2u here:  http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2023/08/13#041_r2u_and_codespaces  Here `t2u` shines because `install.packages("sf")` gives you the binary package _and_ the required library.  So no need for `gdal-config` as `sf` is already compiled and made.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use the `sf` package specifically, but had a similar issue with another package.

You've probably already tried this, but typing `conda install -c conda-forge gdal` into my Mac terminal, instead of creating a conda environment manually, sorted it.

Comment: This did not work. The reason might have been the use of `renv` as explained in [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76919547/2704342).

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by considering an additional factor: I have been using [renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/), which apparently added an additional layer of complexity.

Solution:

1. Deactivate the renv-envrionnent in R using `renv::clean()`
2. Rund the installation of the `sf` package

Limitation: This option is not optimal as it does not allow my to continue using my project library, containing all my R packages. But at least it allow continuing working for the moment.

Nevertheless, any additional solutions that allow to continue using `renv` are welcome. I assume that the hint from [Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel)   on the missing 'gdal-config' in the '$PATH' might be a good starting point.